# angular 8 can download pdf but not rt file

Tags: angular, rtf

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!
I am using Angular 8 and I am able to download pdf with the following code. But I cannot do it for rtf:

In my lab-viewer-pdf.component.html:

```
            <div style="height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
                <object type="application/rtf" [data]="pdfData | safe" height="100%" width="100%">

                </object>
            </div>
```

In my lab-viewer-pdf.component.ts:

```
                import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
            import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-lab-viewer-rtf',
              templateUrl: './lab-viewer-rtf.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./lab-viewer-rtf.component.css']
            })
            export class LabViewerRTFComponent implements OnInit {

              apiURL: string = environment.baseUrl;
              pdfData: any;
              constructor() { }

              ngOnInit() {
                var work_data = localStorage.getItem("l_id");
                this.pdfData = "data:application/rtf;base64," +  work_data;

              }
            }
```

In my home.component.html:

```
                selectLab(contentType: string, data) {
                localStorage.setItem("l_id", data);
                //let url = this.apiURL + `/ExtenalSites/FlowLabs/#/LabViewer`
                let url = '';

                if (contentType === 'PDF')
                {
                  url = `/#/LabViewerPDF`;
                }
                else if (contentType === 'RTF')
                {
                  url = `/#/LabViewerRTF`;
                }

                window.open(url);


              }
```

When I tried to download rtf I get a plugin is required error in google chrome. This is my lab-viewer-rtf.component.html:

```
<div style="height: 100vh; width: 100%;">
<object type="application/rtf" [data]="pdfData | safe" height="100%" width="100%">

</object>
</div>
```

This is my lab-viewer-rtf.component.ts:

```
                import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
            import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

            @Component({
              selector: 'app-lab-viewer-rtf',
              templateUrl: './lab-viewer-rtf.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./lab-viewer-rtf.component.css']
            })
            export class LabViewerRTFComponent implements OnInit {

              apiURL: string = environment.baseUrl;
              pdfData: any;
              constructor() { }

              ngOnInit() {
                var work_data = localStorage.getItem("l_id");
                this.pdfData = "data:application/rtf;base64," +  work_data;

              }
            }
```

error image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

unlike pdf documents whose display is supported natively by browsers, you cannot display rtf file directly from webbrowser. the user must download your rtf file from your webserver and open it with appropriate software (MS Word, Open Office). 
for that depending your webserver you must add these header to your response :

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
Response.Headers["Content-Transfer-Encoding"] = "Binary";
Response.Headers["Content-disposition"] = "attachment; filename=\"fileName.rtf\"";
```